# How to arrange images in rows and use lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have eight pictures I am trying to have on a page with 4 in each row that are sized and aligned with each other.  I had this all figured out before but lost my code.  I have the images all the same size but I can't get them to be in two rows 4 in each and I can't get lightbox to work.  I'm not sure if it is because I am using a div box or what.  **How do I get the first four photos in a row and the second in a second row where they will all be aligned?  Am I doing something wrong because lightbox won't work**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Amber & Melissa Engagement</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ecp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
 <div class=:"flowerLogo">
 <img src="img/engagementheader.png" style="width:100%">
 </div>
 <div class="partners">
 <div class="picture">
 <a href="https://azoltek.000webhostapp.com/ElizabethChristina/img/engagement1.png"     data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="img/engagement1.png"/></a>
<div class="picture">   
<a href="https://azoltek.000webhostapp.com/ElizabethChristina/img/engagement2.png"     data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="img/engagement2.png"/></a>
<div class="picture"> 
<a href="https://azoltek.000webhostapp.com/ElizabethChristina/img/engagement3.png"     data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="img/engagement3.png"/></a>
<div class="picture">
<a href="https://azoltek.000webhostapp.com/ElizabethChristina/img/engagement4.png"     data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="img/engagement4.png"/></a>
<div class="partners">
<div class="picture">

 <a     href="https://azoltek.000webhostapp.com/ElizabethChristina/img/engagement5.png"     data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="img/engagement5.png"/></a>
 <div class="picture">
 <a href="https://azoltek.000webhostapp.com/ElizabethChristina/img/engagement6.png"     data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="img/engagement6.png"/></a>
<div class="picture">
 <a       href="https://azoltek.000webhostapp.com/ElizabethChristina/img/engagement7.png"     data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="img/engagement7.png"/></a>
<div class="picture">
 <a     href="https://azoltek.000webhostapp.com/ElizabethChristina/img/engagement8.png"     data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="img/engagement8.png"/></a>

</div>
```

I have all of the div boxes closed but I'm not going to write all of that out.  Here is the CSS code:

```
.partners{
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;

}


.picture{ 
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 20px;
display: table-cell;

}
.picture img{
height: 450px;
width: 300px;  
padding: 20px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to ask a question, smenon.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console in regards to lightbox?

Comment: I'm using Sublime text so I'm not sure where that would show.  Also I'm trying to have the images resize to the window if the window shrinks.  I've googled it and tried some code but its reverting the images to full size and all in one column.

Comment: Okay so I have lightbox working.  But I can't get the icons to show.  I have them under my img folder.  I had to change the jquery that was the problem.  So all I need to do is figure out how to resize the images when the browser window gets smaller and get the images for lightbox to work.